# Config reverse DNS PTR on cpanel with AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, smtp, cpanel, amazon-route53

Anybody here has experience with configuration SMTP on Cpanel host by AWS EC2.

After I have done configurations, DKIM is valid, SPF is valid, but PTR is not valid (reverse DNS). Then when I sent a test email to mail-tester.com, it was 3/10. Here is the error message

```
We didn't find a server (A Record) behind your hostname ip-172-31-1-135.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal.

You may want to publish a DNS record (A type) for the hostname 
ip-172-31-1-135.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal or use a different hostname in your mail software.
```

I'm a newbie for DNS stuff, if you need more information, please give me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should configure your mail server software to use your custom hostname (for example `mail.example.com`), not the AWS assigned default (such as `ip-172-31-1-135.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal`)
2. You need to contact AWS support to have PTR record configured https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/
3. Keep in mind that Amazon EC2 throttles traffic on port 25 of all EC2 instances by default, but you can request for this throttle to be removed: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Comment: Thanks Dusan Bajic,
1. I have done, if I don't change to my custom hostname, I can't install Cpanel

2. Ya true, I read this article already, just not sure how to do it, now I know.

3. Oh God, you save my life, understand, I will change to different port for my SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to receive emails on this server you can't change port number from 25 to something else as other servers will try to connect on this port to deliver emails. You also have to ask AWS to remove throttle on port 25 as stated before.

If you haven't already, create A DNS record for cpanel.mydomain.com pointing to your elastic IP (it is important that you have elastic IP not automatically assigned public IP)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got 9.8/10 after tweaking some configuration and waiting for AWS Support to map Elastic IP to my domain name, then I can get 10/10

[image]

Most importantly, have to make sure hostname has to your my domain
1. set hostname
`sudo hostname cpanel.mydomain.com`

2. Set it automatically

```
cd /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/
sudo nano set-hostname.sh
```

`file set-hostname.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
hostname cpanel.mydomain.com
/scripts/fixetchosts
```

For more detail, please free to reference [here](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-cpanel-whm-on-aws-ec2-instance/)